# Is there any logic on the basis of which excel stores dates as numbers or text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a logical explanation why dates are converted to numbers >40000 as illustrated below: -

Example: **3/2/2020** when converted to text is represented as **438920**

I know the solution to this but only wanted to understand what is the logical journey it follows. Any help would be appreciated.:)

Thanks

Comment: What formula you use? `=TEXT()`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/) will answer your question. Basically Excel counts the days passed from 01/01/1900.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey thanks for the link. I have good clarity of it now.

Comment: @WasifHasan I use the text formula to correct it but I posted this question to just understand what is the logic for values 40000. :)

Answer (score 0):

Excel counts the number of days sinces 01/01/1900 to store date and time. So what you are seeing is the number of days between 3/2/2020 and 1/1/1900